# How to create custom query by keyword in post title?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, loop

I need some help regarding Custom Query by keyword.

I send a keyword to my page where I would like to list those posts which post_title contains the keyword I sent.

Here comes my query as follows:

```
$q = 'SELECT guid, post_content, post_title, post_parent, post_type FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_title REGEXP '".$keyword."') AND post_type="attachment"';
```

How would it be possible to implement it into Wordpress and make it work?

I have seen many snipets but it's really hard for me to make it work.

I have found a code which seemed good, but the displaying part is missing, please see at the end of this question.

```
global $wpdb;
// If you use a custom search form
$keyword = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['mykey'] );
// If you use default WordPress search form
// $keyword = get_search_query();
$keyword = "%{$keyword}%";
// Search in all custom fields
$post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );
// Search in post_title and post_content
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
OR post_content LIKE '%s'
", $keyword, $keyword ) );
$post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post );
// Query arguments
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post__in' => $post_ids,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
// Do loop here
endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Codex has quite an extensive article on this - [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query).

In a nutshell:

```
// retrieve posts using our custom SQL (note that you should query * rather than pick fields)
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

// this is global variable that WP functions rely on for output
global $post;

// loop
foreach($posts as $post) {

    // get global stuff filled current post
    setup_postdata($post);

   // use template tags and profit
   the_title();
}

// cleanup after ourselves
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the post with the keyword like this;

```
<?php // Post Query
$args=array(
's'      => $keyword, 
);
?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```